# Angular 5, Material 5 rc0 - modal is "unpoppable"

Tags: angular, angular-material

This thing is driving me nuts. Look at [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rnj97t). Why is it giving me this error?

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[MatDialogRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError[MatDialogRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!
```

Open the console to see it.

Comment: Whoever downvoted it - any reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I f... done it!** Here we go - https://angular-rnj97t.stackblitz.io

BTW, I know how to kill Chrome in stackblitz with this modal implementation :)

Comment: How did you get it work? There is no code in your link.

Answer (score -1):

That's because it appears that they have changed the entrypoints for each module. You have to import `MatDialogModule`, `MatDialog`, etc. from `@angular/material/dialog` and `MatButtonModule` from `@angular/material/button`. It appears that they did not state this change, however.

You also forgot to import `BrowserAnimationsModule` from `@angular/platform-browser/animations` and forgot to declare a theme in your `styles.css`.

See this [updated demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/modal-dialog-so) (I also changed it up to remove `@Input()` and to use `componentInstance` instead)

Comment: What I don't understand is how I use Modal dialog without injecting MatDialog in AppComponent. Basically, I have a container component with @Input() isOpen: Observable<boolean> and then a modal component which is a child of the container...

Comment: You can use the `componentInstance` property as I stated above. Something like `let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialog); dialogRef.componentInstance.data = "TEST"` and ensure that the `MyDialog` component has that property declared.

Comment: Please let me understand. So how does this modal works? I'm trying to have a common ShowErrorModal component at the AppComponent level so I could use it globally within my app. And I use ngrx for this, that's why I had this ModalContainer. But now I'm lost completely...